# Symfony2-Doctrine ManyToMany with 3 fields related

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I'm having problems to define an association mapping and I don't know what to do to solve.

I want build a relation Many to Many between two objects but not only for one field.

One table refers to persons and the other to image, the target of this relation is represent when a person has been tagged by other person for this image

I need something like this:

---

### |    Tagged   |    Tagger   | Photo      |

### | person_id_1 | person_id_2 | image_id_1 |

### | person_id_3 | person_id_2 | image_id_1 |

### | person_id_2 | person_id_4 | image_id_2 |

I try it using many to many relations like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Media")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="persons_tagged",
 *  joinColumns={
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_tagged", referencedColumnName="id"),
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_tagger", referencedColumnName="id")
 *  },
 *  inverseJoinColumns={
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="media_id",referencedColumnName="id")
 *  }
 * )
 **/
 private $employeeTagged;
```

When I try to update the schema by console, the table in DB it is created but without foreign keys because an exception of foreign key definition is threw and I have to create the foreign keys manually.

Someone has had a similar problem or a way to solve it? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create a new entity which has link to image, link to tagger (user), link to tagged (user).

You might also want to add created datetime, updated datetime, portion of image this person is in, description/text, etc.

Comment: Actually this sounds like the best and easiest solution to me.

Comment: I totally agree with this answer. I used the same approach in the past. You simply break many-to-many into many-to-one + one-to-many.